# How to compare a string with each string in a list in js?

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, jasmine

The problem is,

```
Given a word and a list of possible anagrams, selects the correct sublist.

Given "listen" and a list of candidates like "enlists" "google"
"inlets" "banana"` the program should return a list containing
"inlets".
```

The test cases given are of type:

```
var anagram = require('./anagram');

describe('Anagram', function() {

  xit("detects simple anagram",function() {
    var subject = anagram("ant");
    var matches = subject.matches(['tan', 'stand', 'at']);

    expect(matches).toEqual(['tan']);
  });
});
```

Here is what I have been thinking,

1. Take in the given word, split each character and sort it alphabetically
2. Take in the list, split it to words, take each word and split each character and sort it alphabetically
3. Compare the result of 1 with 2, if a string matches, return its original form.

But the problem is, I don't know how to begin, please help.

Comment: What is the result of `anagram("ant");`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your thinking is correct, here's how you can implement it:

```
var anagrams = function( input, wordlist ){
    // sort the input word
    var sortedinput = input.split('').sort().join(''); 
    // filter the array by checking if...
    return wordlist.filter( function( word ){
        // ...the word after sorting matches the sorted input
        return word.split('').sort().join('') == sortedinput; 
    });
}

anagrams( 'listen', ["enlists", "google", "inlets", "banana"] );
// ["inlets"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2kkvw4u5/

Comment: OK, I got the idea. But somehow its not passing the test. I am getting TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined.

Comment: It won't pass the test posted in your question, because the test expects that `anagram()` returns an object which exposes a `matches` method that takes an array as argument.

Comment: Aha! Got it. But now have another problem, it fails case insensitivity. This test http://jsfiddle.net/j8xhvqng/

Comment: Just add `.toLowerCase()` before `.split()` in both places. But is this some homework-over-the-internet kind of question? You should be able to look up "string to lower case in javascript".

Comment: Yes, this is a puzzle that helps you learn javascript. BTW it still fails here http://jsfiddle.net/j8xhvqng/1/

Comment: Just post all the test cases in your question. It's a nice TDD learning approach, but revealing the requirements one by one is counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

After splitting the current word into char array:

1. iterate over the list of words;
2. check the length of the array if it's equal with the compared word char array;
3. sort the compared word char array and the current word char array, and check each elements if are equal for all indexes in that array.

Comment: Nice optimization with length check before splitting and sorting!